# glob pattern doesn't expand inside file in zsh

Tags: terminal, zsh

I am trying to exclude a directory from a glob.

This works at the command line:

```
$ export exclude=BigDir
$ for d in ^$exclude/ ; do echo "$d" ; done
SmallDir/
SmallerDir/
$
```

But in a file it doesn't work at all

```
#!/bin/zsh

exclude=BigDir
for d in ^$exclude/ ; do echo "$d" ; done
```

Running `./test` or however I saved it prints the *literal* string

```
^BigDir/
```

How do I get it to correctly expand in the script file?

Comment: Which shell is your default? `bash` or `zsh`? You have defined the interpreter for the latter in your script

Comment: @Inian zsh is my default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are incorrectly using the glob characters `?` used by the shell and the regular expression constructs `^`, `$`. The `for` loop in your example can *not* undergo a regex match to exclude the directory provided, since it undergoes only pathname expansion (aka. glob expansion)

Unless you let know the shell to treat `^` and `$` as special by enabling extended glob options `extglob` in `bash` and `extendedglob` in `zsh`, you cannot achieve what you wanted to do.

So you probably just need

```
setopt extendedglob
print -rl ^BigDir*
```

meaning print *anything* except the the filenames matching with `BigDir`.

Comment: I actually don't understand this answer at all, but putting `setopt extendedglob` at the top of my script file fixed my problem.

Comment: @minseong You probably have `setopt extendedglob` in a configuration file somewhere, so that the option is already enabled in your interactive shell. That option isn't inherited by the shell that your script runs in, which is why you need to turn the option on explicitly in the script.